# Rock Paper Scissors Veryfing if tie dont work

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am making a Rock Paper Scissors game in python but with a few new things and when the function checkifwin() is checking for tie it puts the win or lose resultat too

```
import random



user_input = input('Rock, paper, gun, human, water, air, fire or scissors: ')

rpc_options = ['rock','paper','scissors','fire','gun','human','water','sponge','air']

def checkifwin():
  if defeats[user_input] == terminal_response:
    print('You win')
  if not defeats[user_input] == terminal_response:
    print('You lose')
  if user_input == terminal_response:
    print('We tied')
    



if user_input not in rpc_options: 
  print(f'\nYour answer is incorrect; it should be in this list: {rpc_options}\nYour answer is: {user_input}, do you see the error? Lets try again')
else:
  defeats = {
    'air' : ['fire', 'rock', 'water', 'gun'],
    'gun' : ['rock', 'fire', 'scissors', 'human'],
    'paper' : ['air', 'rock', 'water', 'gun'],
    'rock' : ['scissors', 'sponge', 'fire', 'human'],
    'scissors' : ['air', 'paper', 'human', 'sponge'],
    'fire' : ['sponge', 'paper', 'human', 'scissors'],
    'water' : ['rock', 'fire', 'scissors', 'gun'],
    'sponge' : ['water', 'paper', 'gun', 'air'],
    'human' : ['sponge', 'paper', 'air', 'water'],
    }

  terminal_response = random.choice(rpc_options)
  
  print(f'\nYou choose {user_input}, I choose {terminal_response}')

  checkifwin()
```

The resultat if tie:

```
Rock, paper, gun, human, water, air, fire or scissors: paper

You choose paper, I choose paper
You lose
We tied
```

Comment: When you check win and do `defeats[user_input]`, you get back a list but the terminal input is a string. Try starting there. Also, instead of `if....if...if...`, you should change the last two checks to `elif` so that you don't satisfy multiple mutually-exclusive conditions.

Answer (score 2):

`defeats[user_input]` is a list. `terminal_response` is a string. They will never be `==`. You want to use `in`, not `==`.

You should also test for a tie first, because when there's a tie the response will not be in the `defeats` list.

```
if user_input == terminal_response:
    print('We tied')
elif terminal_response in defeats[user_input]:
    print('You win')
else:
    print('You lose')
```